# Route not defined even though I set them

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a signup form and a login form in one page:

```
            <div class="col-md-6 col-centered col-reg">
            <h2>Registreer</h2>
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('signup') }}">
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('regName') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Naam</label> @if($errors->has('regName')) <span style="color: darkred;">{{ $errors->first('regName') }}</span> @endif<br>
                    <input type="text" name="regName" class="form-control" value="{{ old('regName') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('regEmail') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Email</label> @if($errors->has('regEmail')) <span style="color: darkred;">{{ $errors->first('regEmail') }}</span> @endif<br>
                    <input type="email" name="regEmail" class="form-control" value="{{ old('regEmail') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('regPassword') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Wachtwoord</label> @if($errors->has('regPassword')) <span style="color: darkred;">{{ $errors->first('regPassword') }}</span> @endif<br>
                    <input type="password" name="regPassword" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Nogmaals Wachtwoord</label> @if($errors->has('password_confirmation')) <span style="color: darkred;">{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</span> @endif<br>
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Registreer" name="regSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered col-log">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label><br>
                    <input type="email" name="logEmail" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Wachtwoord</label><br>
                    <input type="password" name="logPassword" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="logSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            </form>
        </div>
```

And in the form action I have linked a route and set them in my web.php, like this:

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "forms"], function() {
   Route::post('/', 'PostController@login')->name('login');
   Route::post('/', 'PostController@signUp')->name('signup');
});
```

But I get an error message like this:

> Route [login] not defined

Even though I created them in my web.php and grouped them.

My route list:

[image: Route List]

Why do I get this error? (New to laravel by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined 2 routes with the same `Request Method` and with the same `Route`, that just doesn't add along, try:

```
Route::post('/login', 'PostController@login')->name('login');
```

If you dont want to change your login URL you can change url of your `register` route, but the point is that **you can't have two routes with the same Request Method and same URL**.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but isn't that the URL it goes to when I click submit? I dont want it to go to /login, when I submit it, it has to redirect me to my home page, do I set that in the controller or?

Comment: So you want your login to go to your home, where should your register go to then? Which url?

Comment: They both should go to my home

Comment: But you are not defining where they **will go** but where **they are** and you can't have **two routes with same locations and request method (post, get, delete, patch, etc..)**

Comment: Ahhh okey I understand :) My problem is solved, thanks for your help :)